# vba public variables with changing months

Tags: vba, excel, variables, public

I'm a begginer at VBA so i have no idea what's is wrong. My point is to name some sheets but i thought i could dim them as string. I made public variable but vba dosent see it. Could somebode tell what is excatly wrong?

```
Public Sub VariableMonths()
    Public one, two, three, DeleteIt As String

    one = "M_11_17"
    two = "M_10_17"
    three = "M_09_17"
    DeleteIt = "M_08_17"
End Sub
```

then some part after this public sub - no variable is found

```
Sheets(two).Copy Before:=Sheets(4)
Sheets(two & "( 2)").Select
Sheets(two & "( 2)").Move Before:=Sheets(two)
Sheets(two & "( 2)").Select
Sheets(two & "( 2)").Name = one
Sheets(two).Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
```

Comment: put `Public one as String, two as String, three as String, DeleteIt As String` at the top of the module and remove `Public one, two, three, DeleteIt As String` from inside the sub.  Then run the first to assign the values.

Comment: `Public` isn't legal at procedure scope. Use `Dim` to declare local variables. Public variables cannot be declared in a procedure scope.

Comment: If you need them to be `Public` for some reason, define them outside of the procedure at the top of your module.

Comment: Perhaps, these should be `Public Const`

Answer (score 1):

In a standard Module:

```
Dim one As String, two As String, three As String, DeleteIt As String

Sub setupVariables()
    one = "M_11_17"
    two = "M_10_17"
    three = "M_09_17"
    DeleteIt = "M_08_17"
End Sub

Sub MAIN()
    Call setupVariables
    MsgBox three
End Sub
```

[image]